# How can I see the depth/mist of an animation in compositing?

Tags: animation, compositing-nodes

I am making a scene in Eevee and rendered it out as an OpenEXR image sequence. I tried to composite the animation but when I go into compositing and use try to use depth or mist, the rendered layers node does not show the full animation (just the last frame). I tried to use the image sequence of the animation with the OpenEXR format but I can't get a depth or mist pass.